# Creating objects with methods using 'this' in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am a proficient c# programmer, and I have a little bit of experience with HTML and Javascript, but I can't seem to figure out objects.

I am attempting to create a loop, which just keeps updating until the counter reaches 5 then stops the loop.  but in the Update method counter = NaN.

This is my exact code.

```
function LoginScreen() {
    this.IntervalID = null;
    this.counter = 0;

    this.Start = function () {
        this.IntervalID = setInterval(this.Update, 60 / 1000);
    };

    this.Stop = function () {
        clearInterval(this.IntervalID);
    };

    this.Update = function () {

        this.counter++;
        alert(this.counter);

        if (this.counter > 5) this.Stop();
    };

}

LS = new LoginScreen();
LS.Start();
```

Comment: Are you trying to loop every minute? If so, check the `setInterval()` parameter.

Comment: I doesn't matter how often it loops, my interval is actually 60 times a second but not relevant to this question at this time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is scope of the inner `this` of your `Start()`, `Stop()` and `Update()` functions. Within those functions, `this` is referring to the function, and not your `LoginScreen` object.

To get around these problems, I like to use a little `self` variable to help with scope issues. That way, whatever is referring to the `self` variable will use the object. Here's what I mean:

```
function LoginScreen() {

    // add this for scope fun...
    var self = this;

    this.IntervalID = null;
    this.counter = 0;

    this.Start = function () {
        self.IntervalID = setInterval(self.Update, 60 / 1000); // updated...
    };

    this.Stop = function () {
        clearInterval(self.IntervalID); // updated...
    };

    this.Update = function () {
        self.counter++; // updated...
        alert(self.counter); // updated...

        if (self.counter > 5) self.Stop(); // updated...
    };
}

LS = new LoginScreen();
LS.Start();
```

Hope this makes sense!

Comment: WoW....  it does make sense, but... WoW... who designed this.  I see my head is going to hurt trying to learn javascript after c#.  Is this really the accepted way of doing this?

Comment: The "looseness" of scope is something I both appreciate and cry over in JavaScript...good luck, and keep learning! ;)

Comment: JavaScript is a love/hate relationship. You get used to it. :)

Answer (score 2):

You ran into the dreaded Javascript "this" problem.

Try changing your this.Update code to:

```
var self = this;
this.Update = function () {

        self.counter++;
        alert(self.counter);

        if (self.counter > 5) self.Stop();
    };
```

But wait there is [more](http://www.oreillynet.com/pub/a/javascript/excerpts/javascript-good-parts/awful-parts.html)

Comment: Good answer but Chris beat you to it

Answer (score 2):

This is a very common mistake in Javascript. I think everyone including me did this at one point. It is fairly easy to understand, though.

## What's going on

When you call a function as a method of an object, you set its *context* to the object. That means that `this` inside this function will point to your context object.

```
MyObject = {};
MyObject.someValue = 1;

MyObject.myMethod = function() {
    console.log(this.someValue); // This will log "1" to the console, as expected
};
```

Now comes the tricky part: You can change the context of a function. Let's add some more lines of code here:

```
MyOtherObject = {};
MyOtherObject.someValue = 2;
MyOtherObject.myMethod = MyObject.myMethod;
```

When you now call `MyOtherObject.myMethod` you call the same function as if you would call `MyObject.myMethod`, but in one case `this` points to `MyObject` and in the other case it points to `MyOtherObject`.

Now, when you call `setInterval(MyObject.myMethod, 1000)`, the functions context will be set to `window` (technically, `setInterval` calls `window.setInterval`) and since `window` does not have a property called `someValue`, it will just be undefined.

## How to fix it

To fix this, you can create another reference to your LoginScreen object. It will always point to the same object inside the entire scope, unless you change it. You can then use it as an alternative to `this` without worrying about the context.

```
function LoginScreen() {
    this.IntervalID = null;
    this.counter = 0;

    // Create another reference to "this"
    var self = this;

    this.Start = function () {
        // The function behind "this.Update" will always be called with "window"
        // as its context.
        this.IntervalID = window.setInterval(this.Update, 60 / 1000);
    };

    this.Stop = function () {
        // This function is called as "self.Stop", therefore "this" points to
        // "self", which points to the right object, so you can use "this".
        clearInterval(this.IntervalID);
    };

    this.Update = function () {
        // Inside this function, "this" points to "window".
        // You therefore have to use the previously declared "self"
        // to point to the right object.
        self.counter++;
        alert(self.counter);

        if (self.counter > 5) self.Stop();
    };

}

LS = new LoginScreen();
LS.Start();
```

## Further reference

**[this - Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)** Another explanation of the beviour of *this* in JavaScript, along with some functions to control it.

Comment: Wow...super explanation!